# Python: Effective reading from a file using csv module

Tags: python, file, csv, text

I have just started learning csv module recently. Suppose we have this CSV file:

```
John,Jeff,Judy,
21,19,32,
178,182,169,
85,74,57,
```

And we want to read this file and create a dictionary containing names (as keys) and totals of each column (as values). So in this case we would end up with:

```
d = {"John" : 284, "Jeff" : 275, "Judy" : 258}
```

So I wrote this code which apparently works well, but I am not satisfied with it and was wondering if anyone knows of better or more efficient/elegant way of doing this. Because there's just too many lines in there :D (Or maybe a way we could generalize it a bit - i.e. we would not know how many fields are there.)

```
d = {}
import csv
with open("file.csv") as f:
    readObject = csv.reader(f)

    totals0 = 0
    totals1 = 0
    totals2 = 0
    totals3 = 0

    currentRowTotal = 0
    for row in readObject:
        currentRowTotal += 1
        if currentRowTotal == 1:
            continue

        totals0 += int(row[0])
        totals1 += int(row[1])
        totals2 += int(row[2])
        if row[3] == "":
            totals3 += 0

f.close()

with open(filename) as f:
    readObject = csv.reader(f)
    currentRow = 0
    for row in readObject:   
        while currentRow <= 0:
            d.update({row[0] : totals0}) 
            d.update({row[1] : totals1}) 
            d.update({row[2] : totals2})
            d.update({row[3] : totals3}) 
            currentRow += 1
    return(d)
f.close()
```

Thanks very much for any answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the top row to figure out what the column headings are. Initialize a dictionary of totals based on the headings.

```
import csv

with open("file.csv") as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)

  titles = next(reader)
  while titles[-1] == '':
    titles.pop()
  num_titles = len(titles)      
  totals = { title: 0 for title in titles }

  for row in reader:
    for i in range(num_titles):
      totals[titles[i]] += int(row[i])

print(totals)
```

Let me add that you don't have to close the file after the `with` block. The whole point of `with` is that it takes care of closing the file.

Also, let me mention that the data you posted appears to have four columns:

```
John,Jeff,Judy,
21,19,32,
178,182,169,
85,74,57,
```

That's why I did this:

```
  while titles[-1] == '':
    titles.pop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you can use pandas, but you can get your dict as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(dict(df.sum()))
```

Gives:

```
{'Jeff': 275, 'Judy': 258, 'John': 284}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little dirty, but try this (operating without the empty last column):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import numpy

with open("file.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)

    sums = reduce(numpy.add, [map(int,x) for x in reader], [0]*len(headers))
    for name, total in zip(headers,sums):
        print("{}'s total is {}".format(name,total))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on Michasel's solution, I would try with less code and less variables and no dependency on `Numpy`:

```
import csv

with open("so.csv") as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  titles = next(reader)
  sum_result = reduce(lambda x,y: [ int(a)+int(b) for a,b in zip(x,y)], list(reader))

  print dict(zip(titles, sum_result))
```